# Azure-DevOps Pipeline fails because of testhost.dll

Tags: testing, azure-devops, xunit

I'm having some troubles with my azure devops testing-pipeline.
I'm using xunit tests and every test-project runs correctly and I can view the test results, but the pipeline fails anyway because of the following error

```
##[error]Testhost process exited with error: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.
##[error]. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
```

Like suggested [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569), I added an additional filter for `testhost.dll` so my yaml-snippet looks like this:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
      !**\testhost.dll
      !*testhost.dll
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
```

However, the error still occurs and my Build is marked as failed.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a way to exclude `testhost.dll` for `testSelector`: `testPlan` instead of `testSelector`:`testAssemblies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569) should hopefully help.

Things to try:

- remove references from one test assembly to another
- update Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK to 16.6.1
- add an application.runtimeconfig.json file

Hope this helps!