# VSTEST@2 - error could not find testhost | Azure Pipelines

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-pipelines, vstest

I'm running tests solution on azure pipeline with help of vstest@2 task.
Pipeline distributes test cases on 4 agents and then runs them.

Task yaml:

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        **/*.Tests.dll
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      distributionBatchType: basedOnExecutionTime
      runInParallel: true
```

On beginning of the run I get bunch of these messages :

```
##[error]DiscoveryMessage : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Could not find testhost
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
```

and after that tests start passing and run goes further.

I have two questions about this - what does these messages actually mean / should I intervene in some way?

Can I somehow disable these messages so they dont spam my run log ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below workaround to resolve the above issue, instead of using `**/*.Tests.dll` try to use `**\*test.dll`

```
- task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*test.dll
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      distributionBatchType: basedOnExecutionTime
      runInParallel: true
```

And also based on the [***MS DOC***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?msclkid=2c0abaa4c23f11eca3d6f7be9bd75a9f&view=azure-devops#does-the-vstest-task-support-running-tests-that-target-multiple-target-frameworks-at-a-time) :

> The VsTest task doesn't support running tests that target multiple
> target frameworks at a time as this is a limitation from the vstest
> platform side. If you want to run tests that belong to multiple target
> frameworks, you'll need multiple instances of the vstest task, one per
> set of dlls that target a particular framework.

For more information please refer the below links for the similar issue:

- [***Developer community|error when running VStest from Yaml pipeline***](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-when-running-vstest-from-yaml-pipeline/1690385)
- [***SO THREAD|Azure-DevOps Pipeline fails because of testhost.dll***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62090915/azure-devops-pipeline-fails-because-of-testhost-dll)

Comment: Workaround didn't work and all tests are based on same platform altho thank you a lot for giving me a clue , I've investigated our app files and there are multiple dll's which match pattern that arent supposed to be run and I guess that it is the reason of errors

Comment: @cyman1998 , Thanks you steered me in the right direction. My test was actually also looking in the packages folder so I excluded that from the tests and it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

So I'm using:

```yaml
inputs:
  testAssemblyVer2: |
    **\*Tests*.dll
    !**\*TestAdapter.dll
    !**\obj\**
    !**\bin\**\ref\**
```

From: https://zimmergren.net/unable-to-find-deps-json-dotnet-azure-devops/

Apparently reference assemblies can cause a failure to find the testhost.